# DB Manager in QGIS 3.8 Zanzibar unable to load from PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am no longer able to load tables from PostGIS (PostgreSQL 9.6) since the last update of QGIS. On polygon tables, the DB manager now shows a ? icon, point icon, line icon and polygon icon for each table whether they have those geoms or not. Worse, when attempting to laod it each ask for the CRS yet still none will load into QGIS, even when they contain those geoms. 
See image attached. Is anyone else experiencing these issues and is there a solution to this problem?

[image: qgis image]

Comment: As per the [help/on-topic] it is OK to try and reproduce software problems in a Q&A here, but if you think this is a bug then be sure to submit it to the QGIS development team. Please post a link to the bug report here.

Comment: Can you check your `public.geometry_columns` view to check if your geographic tables are properly registered?

Comment: I assume this is expected behaviour; your geometry column has the generic type `GEOMETRY(GEOMETRY)`, which is capable of storing all geometry types (all of point, line, polygon). QGIS requires layer to have a specific geometry type, and offers to load those as separate layers from the same table. and/or you have to register geometries, as @jgrocha hinted at, for QGIS to read necessary metadata.

Comment: Yes indeed @ThingumaBob and jgrocha the issue appears to be any table with the generic type GEOMETRY(GEOMETRY), Unfortunately, I have hundreds of tables with generic geometry types.   Interesting that 3.6, and every prior version I have used, did not complain and have worked just fine.  I’m relatively new to POSTGIS and QGIS is there a quick method of updating these tables to the correct geom type or will it require updating each one individually?  In the meantime, I have reverted back to QGIS 3.6.

Comment: you could run `UPDATE` commands in an anonymous function block (`DO`); iterate over e.g. `pg_tables`, get the `GeometryType(geom)` (e.g. of the first row) and `UPDATE` the `geom` column using the received string. that get's more involved if the geometry columns don't have a common name, and _way_ more involved if the geometries of a table are in fact not of the same type.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @ThingumaBob. Most of these tables have geom columns with varying names and with multiple geom types so it sounds like they'll need to be addressed on an individual base.  Not feasible at this time so I'll stick with 3.6 for now. Thanks again!

Comment: I just found this https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30787 it appears it has been reported as a bug.